# Parallelize for loop for parsing files

Tags: bash, background-process

I have the following script to parse some `pcap` trace files. There are multiple folders and each folder contains 4 `pcap` files that need to be parsed:

```
for d in * ; 
do cd ${d}; 
for file in firewall router2 vclient vserver ; 
do tshark -r ${file}_log.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e tcp.len -e ip.len -e ip.hdr_len -e tcp.hdr_len -e _ws.col.Time -t e | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$6-$7-$8,$9}' > ${file}_conv_t.txt; 
cat ${file}_conv_t.txt | awk '$4==5001{print $6,$5}' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\.[0-9]*/\1/' | awk '{sum[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in sum) {print i,sum[i]} }' | sort | cut -d ' ' -f 2 > ${file}_in.csv; 
cat ${file}_conv_t.txt | awk '$3==5001{print $6,$5}' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\.[0-9]*/\1/' | awk '{sum[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in sum) {print i,sum[i]} }' | sort | cut -d ' ' -f 2 > ${file}_out.csv ; 
done ; 
cd .. ; 
done
```

Since all the files can be independently parsed, I want to parallelize this as much as possible. I tried putting a `&` instead of `;` after the first `done` so each file gets processed in parallel, like this:

```
for d in * ; 
do cd ${d}; 
for file in firewall router2 vclient vserver ; 
do tshark -r ${file}_log.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e tcp.len -e ip.len -e ip.hdr_len -e tcp.hdr_len -e _ws.col.Time -t e | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$6-$7-$8,$9}' > ${file}_conv_t.txt; 
cat ${file}_conv_t.txt | awk '$4==5001{print $6,$5}' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\.[0-9]*/\1/' | awk '{sum[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in sum) {print i,sum[i]} }' | sort | cut -d ' ' -f 2 > ${file}_in.csv; 
cat ${file}_conv_t.txt | awk '$3==5001{print $6,$5}' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\.[0-9]*/\1/' | awk '{sum[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in sum) {print i,sum[i]} }' | sort | cut -d ' ' -f 2 > ${file}_out.csv ; 
done &
cd .. ; 
done
```

but that did not work at all, it was still sequential.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{}` braces:

```
for d in * ; 
do cd ${d}; 
for file in firewall router2 vclient vserver ; 
do { tshark -r ${file}_log.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e tcp.len -e ip.len -e ip.hdr_len -e tcp.hdr_len -e _ws.col.Time -t e | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$6-$7-$8,$9}' > ${file}_conv_t.txt; 
cat ${file}_conv_t.txt | awk '$4==5001{print $6,$5}' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\.[0-9]*/\1/' | awk '{sum[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in sum) {print i,sum[i]} }' | sort | cut -d ' ' -f 2 > ${file}_in.csv; 
cat ${file}_conv_t.txt | awk '$3==5001{print $6,$5}' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\.[0-9]*/\1/' | awk '{sum[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in sum) {print i,sum[i]} }' | sort | cut -d ' ' -f 2 > ${file}_out.csv ; } &
done
cd .. ; 
done
```

Comment: Can you expand on your answer on how the braces make a difference in bash?